# Combinations algorithm challenge

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to solve this problem for over a month now. 
I have a list of numbers and these variables:

```
list_num = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4]

#x is number of numbers in combination eg. if x = 5 combiantions will look like this [n,n,n,n,n], where n is possible member of list _num
x = 5
#y is a sum of numbers inside combination
y = 10
```

I have a need to generate all possible combinations of this numbers in the way that **`x`** is number of numbers in combination and the **`y`** is the sum of numbers in combination, also the number of repeating inside **`list_num`** must be considered.

I can do this by generating all possible combination and by eliminating the combinations that are not determined by my rules but this method is messy and I cant use it with large number of data. In mine original program **`list_num`** can have hundreds of numbers and variables **`x`** and **`y`** can have large values.

Couple of the combinations for this example:

```
comb1 = [1,1,2,3,3], x = 5, y = 10
comb2 = [1,1,1,2,5], x = 5, y = 10
comb3 = [1,1,1,1,6], x = 5, y = 10

...
```

I would appreciate some new ideas, I do not have any left :)

Comment: Any constraints on `x` and `y`?

Comment: give clear variablenames :)

Comment: Default locale, well obviously x cant be larger of len(num_list) and y must be possible both are integers. Quonux what do you mean by clear variablenames?

Comment: y in comb1, comb2, comb3 is the sum of the numbers.  But it isn't in list_num.  comb1,comb2,comb3 have repeated numbers that are counted.  I don't quite follow your examples and what you mean by "repeating numbers must be counted"

Comment: check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Vorsprung, y is the sum of numbers for single possible combinations. By stating that number of numbers in combinations must be considered i wanted to say that if we had only four ones in list_num comb3 in examples can not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NP-complete problem, please find the optimal solution for this at  :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for directions!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea:

1) Sort the list

2) Use an array A of x elements - these are going to be indexes

3) Initialize A to be [0,1,2,...,x-1]

4) Now start increasing the indexes lexicographical, e.g. first increase the last one until the sum gets >y. Then increase the  second to last and make the last be 1+the second to last

and so on

Fisrt few iterations:

sorted array: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]

A: [0,1,2,3,4]

A: [0,1,2,3,5]

A: [0,1,2,3,6]

A: [0,1,2,3,7]

A: [0,1,2,3,8]

A: [0,1,2,3,9]

A: [0,1,2,3,10] - solution

A: [0,1,2,4,5]

A: [0,1,2,4,6]

A: [0,1,2,4,7]

A: [0,1,2,4,8]

A: [0,1,2,4,9] - solution

A: [0,1,2,4,10] - >y

A: [0,1,2,5,6]

A: [0,1,2,5,7] - solution

etc.

Comment: Interesting I will try this!

Comment: However, this is not what I was looking for but the way it was achieved gave me an idea.

Comment: This idea can be improved by branching out as soon as we reach y. meaning since the array is sorted, you do know that if the combination [0, 1, 2, 3, 6] is greater or equal to y, then [0, 1, 2, 3, 7] is not gonna work either and so directly skip and try [0, 1, 2, 4, 5] directly.

Comment: Well i said this is not what i was looking for and after trying this out I just stroke the brick wall. If even I manage to develop algorithm that works this way computing time increases exponentionaly.

Answer (score 0):

For base 10 output numbers you can just count a variable up, do the sign sum and output the combination if the sign sum is for example 10.

Code:

```
def SignSum(X):
    Sum = 0

    String = str(X)

    for Sign in String:
       Sum += int(Sign)

    return Sum

Counter = 0


while Counter < 10000:
   if SignSum(Counter) == 10:
      print Counter

   Counter += 1
```

this of course works also with other bases with a modified SignSum() function